# A source for integral operators in the context of Arthur-Selberg trace formula

Tags: reference-request, integral-operators, trace-formula

Could you suggest a textbook for integral operators 
(in the context of Arthur-Selberg trace formula)?

Comment: Look at places where it is proved, like the book by Deitmar and Echterhoff.

Comment: what abou http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/mueller/skripte/specauto.pdf

Comment: There is a very good book of N.V.Kuznetsov Trace formulas and applications in analytical number theory-but it is in Russian. Note that a generalization of Selberg formula is called The Kuznetsov Trace formula (name due to Ivaniec, Huxley and Sarnak).Book of P.Sarnak Some applications of modular forms-the classical one.